# Git Error Message During Rebase

Tags: git, error-handling, rebase

I'm trying to rebase my branch in VS2015 to a recently updated `Master` prior to publishing the branch, or continuing in general.  Every time I try to rebase onto `Master`, I get this error message:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: Unstaged changes exist in workdir
```

I've closed the solution, and VS, a couple times and it's still tormenting me.  I've seen it before, but it always seems to go away quickly.  Is it just a waiting game for files to be updates in my source tree?  or is there something I can do to proactively address this?  Any help or links is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any unstaged changes? What's the output of git status?

Comment: No unstaged changes and my output window just says `Rebasing current branch onto refs/heads/master.`...  But it never does anything

Comment: I tried the rebase via command line, but I have merge conflicts and for some reason it was trying to rebase my branch on to a previous version of itself from 2 commits ago...